# How I could get the actual toposhape data in OpenCascade?

Tags: python, c++, computational-geometry, opencascade

All

have file from CAD (SW) in STEP format and was able to read it via Python OCC binding:

```
    importer = aocxchange.step.StepImporter(fname)
    shapes = importer.shapes

    shape = shapes[0]

    # promote up
    if (shape.ShapeType() == OCC.TopAbs.TopAbs_SOLID):
        sol =  OCC.TopoDS.topods.Solid(shape)
```

I could display it, poke at it, check flags etc

```
t = OCC.BRepCheck.BRepCheck_Analyzer(sol)
print(t.IsValid())
print(sol.Checked())
print(sol.Closed())
print(sol.Convex())
print(sol.Free())
print(sol.Infinite())
```

[image]

So far so good. It really looks like small tube bent along some complex path.

Question: how I could extract geometry features from what I have? I really need tube parameters and path it follows. Any good example in Python and/or C++ would be great

Comment: What do you mean by "tube parameters" and "path it follows" ? Are you interested on the underlying geometry (ex.: a bspline curve) ?

Comment: @Fernando yes, underlying geometry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OpenCASCADE there's a separation between topology and geometry. So, usually your first contact will be the topological entities (i.e.: *TopoDS_Wire* or a *TopoDS_Edge*), that can give you access to the geometry ([take a look here](https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.1.0/overview/html/occt_user_guides__modeling_data.html#occt_modat_5) for more details).

In your case, after reading the STEP file you ended up with a [TopoDS_Shape](https://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.1.0/refman/html/class_topo_d_s___shape.html). This is the highest level topological entity and most probably is formed by one or more sub-shapes.

Assuming that your shape is formed by a bspline curve (it seems to be!), you could explore the shape, looking for *TopoDS_Edge* objects (they are the topological entities that map to geometric curves):

```
TopExp_Explorer myEdgeExplorer(shape, TopAbs_EDGE);
while (myEdgeExplorer.More())
{
    double u0, u1;
    auto edge = TopoDS::Edge(myEdgeExplorer.Current());
    auto curve = BRep_Tool::Curve(edge, u0, u1);

    // now you have access to the curve ...
    // to get a point lying on it, check
    // the method curve->Value(u);

    myEdgeExplorer.Next();
}
```